# How to convert existing .fig files to .jpg on matlab

Tags: matlab, jpeg

I have a list of `.fig` files in a directory.

How do I write a simple matlab function that converts all the `.fig` files to `.jpg` files automatically?

Comment: Read the manual! There is a function to open figures and there is a function to save figures into images.

Comment: I would strongly suggest saving matlab figure to `.png` instead of `.jpg`. The `jpg` compression result in a lot of aliasing on your figure, which you wouldn't get with `.png` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matlab figs are just matrices which you have to load into Matlab to interpret and convert, so you can try something like this:

```
fig=openfig(FileName,'new','invisible');
saveas(fig,OutputFileName.jpg,'jpg')
close(fig);
```

The 'invisible' option does not open the fig in a plot, so it saves memory and time.

Answer (score 2):

GameOfThrows' answer was useful in saving a single `.fig` file to `.jpg`

To loop through all the `.fig` files, this worked for me:

```
//obtain the files with .fig extension
files = dir('*.fig');

//loop through the .fig files
for i=1:length(files)

   //obtain the filename of the .fig file
   filename = files(i).name;

   //open the figure without plotting it
   fig = openfig(filename, 'new', 'invisible');

   //save the figure as a jpg
   saveas(fig, 'example.jpg');

   //close the figure so that the next could be opened without some java problem
   close;

end
```